# While Loop insert from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to create parent child table in my DB. My child table is already existed for a long time, so it contained a long list of records.  What i want to do it copy child name to my parents table.

**Child Table**

```
---------------
ChildID | ChildNm
---------------
1        |A
2        |B
3        |C
```

**Parent Table**

```
----------------
ParentID|ParentNm|ChildNm
----------------
```

**Query**

```
WHILE (
        SELECT Min(ChildID)
        FROM ChildTable
        ) <
    SELECT Max(ChildID)
    FROM ChildTable

BEGIN
    --INSERT every child NAME TO my parents TABLE
END
```

Is this the best possible way to do this?

Comment: What if there are multiple children per parent? THe parent table allows only one ChildNm per parent. Also, you can make it *look* the same with a view and a JOIN

Comment: yes, the table allow multiple child, but current requirement is to insert a parent for every child, cause the parent table is new table~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a need for loops, I rarely do.

Try something like this perhaps:

```
insert parent(ChildNm)
select distinct ChildNm from child c
where not exists (select 1 from parent where c.childNm = childNm)

select * from parent
```

I am not sure what you want as parent names

*I am assuming your parent table looks something like this:

```
create table parent(ParentID int identity(1,1), ParentNm char(1), ChildNm char(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Architecture wise this table relationship is not good and completely against the law.

I don't know what purpose you want to solve using this implementation.

According to good approach and practice you need to Add a column "ParentId" in Child table.

And against the every child you can set the parent ID. I am not sure how you will decide that this clild blongs to which parent.

I would suggest to rethink about your approach first.

By the way you can use bulk insert query to insert value in parent table like:

```
   insert into parents (childnm) select  ChildNm from Child group by ChildNm
```